# Adding prefix to specific R columns

Tags: r

I can select specific R columns by using "colnames" and "grepl". For example, to select columns starting with "EXP" and having 3 characters after that, I use the following code:

```
df[ , grepl( "EXP...", names( df) ) ]
```

( # using ... to indicate there should be 3 characters after EXP)

I can store the names of these specific columns by simply adding "colnames" function to the beginning.

```
colnames1 <- colnames(df[ , grepl( "EXP...", names( df) ) ])
```

So far, I have no problems with reaching these specific column names. I use the following code to add a suffix, "New", to these column names:

```
colnames(df[ , grepl( "EXP...", names( df) ) ])
<- paste("New",df(data1[ , grepl( "EXP...", names( df) ) ] ), sep="_")
```

But, it does not work. Shouldn't the names of these columns appear with the suffix ("New_EXP...") after using this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't obliged to use `grepl()`. It's possible to use `gsub()` instead. Since `gsub()` if no match found, returns unchanged values, you can change your column names on the fly, without intermediate indexing step:

#### Example data set

```
sed.seed(66248086) 

(
  dat <- data.frame(
    ID         = 1:3,
    EXPFRQ     = runif(3),
    EXPMETADAT = sample(c(T, F), 3, T),
    .EXPGRP    = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 3, T),
    EXPOUT     = sample(c('*', '**', '***'), 3, T),
    NOTES      = c("Bad project...", "What is in this tube?", "Blot, blot western baby")
    )
  )

#   ID       EXPFRQ EXPMETADAT .EXPGRP EXPOUT                   NOTES
# 1  1 0.5483680151      FALSE       C      *          Bad project...
# 2  2 0.0628816469      FALSE       B     **   What is in this tube?
# 3  3 0.0001267055       TRUE       B    *** Blot, blot western baby
```

#### Actually where renaming takes place

Just give to `gsub()` your pattern, and call the chunk it found using back-reference (`\\1`):

```
colnames(dat) <- gsub('^(EXP[A-Z]{3})$', 'New_\\1', colnames(dat))
```

#### Result

```
dat

#   ID   New_EXPFRQ EXPMETADAT .EXPGRP New_EXPOUT                   NOTES
# 1  1 0.5483680151      FALSE       C          *          Bad project...
# 2  2 0.0628816469      FALSE       B         **   What is in this tube?
# 3  3 0.0001267055       TRUE       B        *** Blot, blot western baby
```

---

**Note**: Please, reade the note written by @akrun under [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66248118/1861328)!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dong the assingment by subsetting the data, the assignment can be done directly on the `names` or `colnames`

```
# // get the index where there are are EXP followed by three characters
i1 <- grep("EXP...", names(df))
# // subset the names with the index, use paste to create new names
nm2 <- paste0(names(df)[i1], "_New")
# // change the column names with the newly created names
names(df)[i1] <- nm2
```

NOTE: NO external packages are needed

Answer (score 1):

A base `R` solution:

```
names(df) <- ifelse(grepl("EXP...", names(df)), paste0("New_", names(df)), names(df))
```

---

You can do this easily with the `dplyr` library using the [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) helper `matches`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::rename_with(~ paste0("New_", .x), matches("EXP.{3}"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a practical way to accomplish what I asked; however, dots do not work as intended. For example, when I try to change the names of the columns that have "2" in the second position of their names (e.g. 32500, 42133), I use the following: contains(".2..."), but it does not work at all.

Comment: Use `matches` instead of `contains` for regular expressions. `contains` evaluates a literal string. For example, use `matches("^.2.{3}")` to apply this to all columns that have a "2" in the second place followed by 3 characters.